# Como adicionar um controle dinamicamente no C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Como adicionar um controle numa página `ASP.NET` dinamicamente usando **C#**?

Comment: Não seria ASP.NET ao invés de somente ASP?

Comment: @MiguelAngelo Corrigido.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Criando um controle `TextBox` dinamicamente:

```
TextBox txtTeste = new TextBox();
txtTeste.ID = "txtTeste";
this.Page.Form.Controls.Add(txtTeste);
```

Para inserir esse componente na tela, é usado o método `this.Page.Form.Controls.Add();` que anexa na página o componente depois dos criados manualmente. *Exemplo: Se você tiver um Botão na tela e inserir dinamicamente o TextBox será criado depois do Botão.*

## Eu consigo inserir o controle na posição que eu quiser?

Sim, usando o método `this.Page.Form.Controls.AddAt(Indice, Controle);` usando o exemplo anterior ficaria assim: `this.Page.Form.Controls.AddAt(0, txtTeste);`

## Controle na MasterPage é adicionado fora do MainContent

Para adicionar um controle na **MasterPage** é feito de uma forma diferente:

```
ContentPlaceHolder MainContent = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("MainContent");
TextBox txtTeste = new TextBox();
txtTeste.ID = "txtTeste";
MainContent.Controls.Add(txtTeste);
```

- O controles adicionado dinamicamente tem todas as propriedades de um controle adicionado manualmente.

### Adicionando e estilizando uma `GridView` dinamicamente:

```
/* Classe exemplo */
public class Aluno
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int? RA { get; set; }

    public Aluno(string nome, int? ra)
    {
        Nome = nome;
        RA = ra;
    }
}
```

No **Page_Load** da tela adicionamos a **Grid** e os dados:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /* Lista criada para popular a Grid */
        List<Aluno> Alunos = new List<Aluno>();
        Alunos.Add(new Aluno("João", 2013));
        Alunos.Add(new Aluno("Maria", 2014));

        GridView gvAlunos = new GridView();
        gvAlunos.ID = "gvAlunos";
        gvAlunos.BorderColor = Color.White; /* Alterando cor da borda da Gridview */
        gvAlunos.HeaderStyle.BackColor = Color.RoyalBlue; /* Alterando a cor do background do Header */
        gvAlunos.HeaderStyle.ForeColor = Color.White; /* Alterando a cor da fonte do Header */
        gvAlunos.DataSource = Alunos;
        gvAlunos.DataBind();
        this.Page.Form.Controls.Add(gvAlunos);
    }
```